# How to set a secondary y-axis in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to change the secondary y-axis values in a matplot graph to `ymin = -1` and `ymax = 2`.  I can't find anything on how to change the values though.  I am using the `secondary_y = True` argument in `.plot()`, so I am not sure if changing the secondary y-axis values is possible for this. I've included my current code for creating the plot.

```
df.plot()
df.plot(secondary_y = "Market")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your example code, it seems you're using Pandas built in ploting capabilities. One option to add a second layer is by using matplotlib directly like in the [example "two_scales.py"](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).

It uses

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(df["..."])
# ...
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df["Market"])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 5])
```

where you can change the y-limits.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was hoping I could used the Pandas built in plot to do this, but it appears that it is not possible. I'll just re-write my code accordingly!

Answer (score 6):

Setting `ylim` on plot does not appear to work in the case of `secondary_y`, but I was able to workaround with this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': range(10), 'two': range(10, 20)})

ax = df['one'].plot()
ax2 = df['two'].plot(secondary_y=True)
ax2.set_ylim(-20, 50)
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

[image: test.png]

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for showing as much y-axes as data columns the dataframe has

```
colors = ['tab:blue',
            'tab:orange',
            'tab:green',
            'tab:red',
            'tab:purple',
            'tab:brown',
            'tab:pink',
            'tab:gray',
            'tab:olive',
            'tab:cyan']

#X axe and first Y axe
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x_label = str( dataFrame.columns[0] )
index = dataFrame[x_label]

ax1.set_xlabel(x_label)
ax1.set_xticklabels(dataFrame[x_label], rotation=45, ha="right")

firstYLabel = str( dataFrame.columns[1] )
ax1.set_ylabel(firstYLabel, color = colors[0])
ax1.plot(index, dataFrame[firstYLabel], color = colors[0])
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor = colors[0])


#Creates subplots with independet y-Axes
axS =[]
def newTwix(label, ax1, index, dataFrame):
    print(label)
    actualPos = len(axS)
    axS.append(ax1.twinx())
    axS[actualPos].set_ylabel(label, color = colors[actualPos%10 + 1])
    axS[actualPos].plot(index, dataFrame[label], color=colors[actualPos%10 + 1])
    axS[actualPos].tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=colors[actualPos%10 + 1])

    identation = 0.075  #would improve with a dynamic solution
    p = 1 + identation
    for i in range(2,len(dataFrame.columns)):
        newTwix(str(dataFrame.columns[i]), ax1, index, dataFrame)
        if (len(axS) == 1):
            axS[len(axS)-1].spines.right.set_position(("axes", p))
        else:
            p = int((p + identation)*1000)/1000
            axS[len(axS)-1].spines.right.set_position(("axes", p))

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.04, right=0.674, bottom=0.1)
    mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    mng.full_screen_toggle()
    
    plt.show()
```

[multiple y-axes with independent scales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9iyk.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
ax= data.plot(kind='line',use_index=True,rot=rot,figsize=size,color='orange',marker='d',xticks= range(0,len(data)))

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data_2.values, linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0,color='deepskyblue')
```